# onchange function not executing on form field change

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-apps-script, onchange

I have a form with only single field (DropDown) and assigned a function to execute on it's change.

But it's not working.

<select type="text" class="form-control" id="searchtext" **onchange="handleFormSubmit(this)"** name="searchtext" placeholder="Search Text">

What went wrong

here is the [WebApp URL](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbw3skZeehbgB46YsoqOgabLRWWgwWqDJ0w-ASrJNncKUeCb4vrKk--a5gem1CgsRDjCeg/exec)

**Code.gs file**

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate()
  .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}


/* PROCESS FORM */
function processForm(formObject){  
  var result = "";
  if(formObject.searchtext){//Execute if form passes search text
      result = search(formObject.searchtext);
  }
  return result;
}

//SEARCH FOR MATCHED CONTENTS 
function search(searchtext){
  var spreadsheetId   = '1fVBNWvZkFMOfnlt8r6fevt-ozTPweiR5oXot1GU4g2A'; //** CHANGE !!!
  var dataRage        = 'Data!A2:D';                                    //** CHANGE !!!
  var data = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadsheetId, dataRage).values;

  var ar = [];
  
  data.forEach(function(f) {
    if (~f.indexOf(searchtext)) {
      ar.push(f);
    }
  });
  return ar;
}
```

**Index.html file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <base target="_top">
        <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-xrRywqdh3PHs8keKZN+8zzc5TX0GRTLCcmivcbNJWm2rs5C8PRhcEn3czEjhAO9o" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        


<!--##JAVASCRIPT FUNCTIONS ---------------------------------------------------- -->
<script>
//PREVENT FORMS FROM SUBMITTING / PREVENT DEFAULT BEHAVIOUR
    function preventFormSubmit() {
        var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
        for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
          forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
              event.preventDefault();
              });
       }
    }
          window.addEventListener("load", preventFormSubmit, true); 
             
          
          //HANDLE FORM SUBMISSION
          function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createTable).processForm(formObject);
            document.getElementById("search-form").reset();
          }
        
          //CREATE THE DATA TABLE
          function createTable(dataArray) {
            if(dataArray && dataArray !== undefined && dataArray.length != 0){
              var result = "<table class='table table-sm' id='dtable' style='font-size:0.8em'>"+
                           "<thead>"+
                             "<tr>"+                     //Change table headings to match witht he Google Sheet
                              "<th scope='col'>Model</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>Price</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>Warranty</th>"+
                              
                           
                            "</tr>"+
                          "</thead>";
              for(var i=0; i<dataArray.length; i++) {
                  result += "<tr>";
                  for(var j=0; j<dataArray[i].length; j++){
                      result += "<td>"+dataArray[i][j]+"</td>";
                  }
                  result += "</tr>";
              }
              result += "</table>";
              var div = document.getElementById('search-results');
              div.innerHTML = result;
            }else{
              var div = document.getElementById('search-results');
              //div.empty()
              div.innerHTML = "Data not found!";
            }
          }
        </script>
        <!--##JAVASCRIPT FUNCTIONS ~ END ---------------------------------------------------- -->
        
    </head>

<style>
    body{
    margin:0;
    padding-top: 10px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
  }

 *{
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

 .table{
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }

 .table td,.table th{
  padding:12px 15px;
  border:1px solid #ddd;
  text-align: center;
  font-size:16px;
  }

  .table th{
    background-color: darkblue;
    color:#ffffff;
  }

  .table tbody td:nth-child(even){
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
  }

  table td:nth-child(1){ display:none;} 

  /*responsive*/

  @media(max-width: 500px){

     .table tr{
        margin-bottom:15px;
     }

     .table td::before{
        left:0;
        font-size:15px;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: left;
     }
    
  }

</style>


<body>
        <div class="container">
      
                  <!-------------------------- SEARCH FORM ----------------------------------------->
                  <form id="search-form" style="margin: 0 auto; width:  50%" >
                    
                    <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2" >
                      <select type="text" class="form-control" id="searchtext" onchange="handleFormSubmit(this)" name="searchtext" placeholder="Search Text">
                        <option> Select </option>
                        <option> FLO </option>
                        <option> TUBULAR </option>
                      </select>
                    </div>

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Search</button>
                  </form>
                  <!-- ## SEARCH FORM ~ END -------------------------------------------->

              <!-- ## TABLE OF SEARCH RESULTS ------------------------------------------>
                <div id="search-results" class="table"  >
                  <!-- The Data Table is inserted here by JavaScript -->
                </div>
              <!-- ## TABLE OF SEARCH RESULTS ~ END ------------------------------------>
                
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, I'm worried that `formObject` might not be able to be parsed with `google.script.run`.
- You might want to run `document.getElementById("search-form").reset()` after `processForm` was finished.

When these points are reflected in your showing script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createTable).processForm(formObject);
  document.getElementById("search-form").reset();
}
```

#### To:

```
function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(e => {
    createTable(e);
    document.getElementById("search-form").reset();
  }).processForm({searchtext: formObject.value});
}
```

### Note:

- **When you modified the Google Apps Script, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.**
- You can see the detail of this in the report "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

Comment: @Prabhu Paul Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: @Prabhu Paul About `Hello @Tanaike can you help me in this Question`, when I saw your new question, I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer.

Comment: @Prabhu Paul Thank you for replying. About `Hi @Tanaike, I tested his answer and presently it is not working brother`, first, I apologize for this. In this case, I would like to recommend commenting on the existing answer.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike as his answer was not working he deleted that.
Can you give your solution there ..?

Comment: @Prabhu Paul Thank you for replying. From your reply, I posted a comment. Please check it.